# kdump fails to log server crash event

Tags: server, 14.04, kernel, crash

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a machine that is experiencing random crashes under load. The server doesn't restart independently, but it becomes inaccessible via ssh or direct KVM connection.

I suspect CPU issues, but I'm looking for a smoking gun, so I'm following the instructions here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe

However, no logfile appears in `/var/crash` after either a natural or induced crash.

---

### Details:

(I induced a crash between each change described here, with no change.)

Everything went smoothly until I got to this step:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/kexec_crash_loaded
0
```

Expected output was 1. A bit of digging led me to `/etc/default/kdump-tools`, where I set `USE_KDUMP=1`. When that didn't work, I added `KDUMP_SYSCTL="kernel.panic=60 kernel.panic_on_oops=1"` based on the [sysctl documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt). Still no joy, so I modified the param directly with `sysctl -w kernel.panic=60` to supposedly add extra time for kdump to do its thing.

In every case, I would run:

```
echo c | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

The computer would crash and reboot as expected, but all I'd see is this:

```
$ ls /var/crash
kexec_cmd
```

`/var/log/kern.log` contains only log entries from boot, not from the crashes. (Not sure if this is expected, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.)

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If `/boot` is on a separate partition, Kernel Crash Dump on Ubuntu will fail because of a ---> [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kexec-tools/+bug/828731) which still exists in 14.04 Trusty, can you believe it? At least it is the case for me using LVM and a separate `/boot`.

The workaround is to

1. `unmount /boot` and then mount it to some other mount point, e.g. `/mnt`
2. copy the contents over to `/boot` (the one on the same block device as `/`). e.g. `rsync -axHAX --progress --stats /mnt/ /boot`
3. Trigger a crash by using `echo c | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger`
4. If all good, you'll see kernel crash dump in `/var/crash` in forms of (uname -r)-yyyymmddHHmm.crash and a yyyymmddHHmm directory with dmesg and dump.

If you want to analyze the crash dump, you'll need `crash`, run it like below:

`crash /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-$(uname -r) /var/crash/yyyymmddHHmm/dump.yyyymmddHHmm`

For more info regarding crash, read the manual.

BTW: DO NOT forget to reload the kdump-tools configuration after changing `/etc/default/kdump-tools` by `kdump-config load`.

Comment: will there be any issue if you unmount /boot? As the grub and the image are on this partition? Will the system reboot successfully after unmount /boot?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is the reserved memory is too small.(my problem caused by this reason).

I think you should check the right thing from three steps.
First, check your config is follow the [Ubuntu kernel Crash dump]:https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html

Second, `dmesg|grep -i crash`, to check the reserved memory is ok.

Third, `service kdump-tools status` to check the load kdump kernel is ok.

In the third step, the log is very important, your can see `/var/log/syslog` to find the logs. and then identify the reason.